# ¿Cómo redirigir en IP a un dominio?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, .htaccess, pretty-urls, dominio

Tengo un dominio apuntando a mi servidor, el cuál tiene la IP 1.1.1.1, en este tengo un reverse proxy con apache para que me apunte a otro servidor interno.

Por lo tanto, el funcionamiento cuando acceden es correcto, entra a www.dominio.com y se ve el index de la web correctamente, el problema viene cuando haces click en los enlaces, se vuelve a ver la IP publica, junto con su puerto.

¿Como podría enmascarar esa IP para que se viese correctamente?

Se ve asi 1.2.3.4:8082/empresa y quiero que ponga dominio.com/empresa, si lo cambio a mano funciona correctamente.

He intentado hacerlo con htaccess y con un virtual host, pero no logro dar con la tecla.

Comment: intentaste el mod_rewrite? `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1\.2\.3\.4
RewriteRule (.*) http://sudominio.com/$1 [R=301,L]` Estp en el htaccess

Comment: Si, pero el problema es, como comento arriba, que la IP es con un puerto y no sé dónde hay que especificarlo, creo que ahí está el error.

Comment: Prueba con `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1\.2\.3\.4:8082
RewriteRule (.*) http://tudominio.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Nada, no funciona. Gracias.

Comment: Recuerda cada vez que hagas cambios, reiniciar el servidor.

Comment: Reinicio apache, entiendo que con eso vale no?